# Where to look next if Windows hangs up with a busy cursor for 5 to 10 minutes, with NO errors in Event Viewer

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze

I am familiar with low level issues in Windows (such as, a hard disk failing, or having a physical error) causing a low level lock/freeze in Windows that lasts either forever, or until the error condition clears.  What I am not used to is figuring out WHERE to look in Windows diagnostic tools, other than Event Viewer after such a major error, to find any errors.

The number one most useful part of Event Viewer in such a case would normally be the Custom Views > Administrative Events filtered view, which gathers a lot of serious information together.  That filter shows NO data for the date today, and its last event was the previous night. The system just recovered after 10 minutes of completely not responding to any keyboard or mouse input.  After 10 minutes, Windows recovered, and I was able to at least open task manager.

During that 10 minutes of "hung" time, the mouse cursor moved when I dragged the mouse around, but nothing else appeared to be happening. It did not appear to leave any indication in any of the usual 10 or 20 places in Event Viewer that I checked (every section in Windows Logs, also everything in the top level Applications in Services Logs).

My guess is I should enable some event viewer logs that are currently disabled. If so, which ones.  If I should go somewhere OTHER than event viewer, which place would be good to check?

If this was linux, I'd be looking at `dmesg` and `journalctl` to look and kernel and system logs, but event viewer is the closest thing to "system logs" that windows actually has.

Update: I have tried to capture ETL trace information with `wpr.exe` but it is failing with an error writing to the disk. it says the disk is full which it can't possibly be, it has >100 gigs free space, and the wpr trace was only running 5 minutes, so I have a hard time believing it wants to log a 100+ gb .etl file. Also, using CrystalDiskInfo and WD utilities, I have checked the hard disk S.M.A.R.T. status, and there are no disk problems reported by either tool.  A sensible explanation for the system wide hang would be a Disk IO problem writing the page file. But then there should be errors in the event viewer.  Inability to do a wpr.exe -stop is odd:

```
wpr.exe -stop C:\hang.etl 
There is not enough space on the disk. 
Profile Id: RunningProfile 
Error code: 0x80070070 There is not enough space on the disk.
```

Comment: It's odd nothing's in the event logs. Storage system errors would definitely be logged. My guess is a non-storage subsystem (CPU?) was saturated, which wouldn't necessarily result in anything being logged. Any chance you can have Resource Monitor or [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) open when this happens so you can observe?

Comment: press CAPS LOCK key during hang and look if status LED toggles or not. If it toggles, it is a software based freeze, if it doesn't toogle, you have a HW issue.

Comment: Good point. I'm starting to suspect that I have a Meltdown/Spectre-mitigation related freeze up in the Windows Kernel layer.  It's a global kernel lock, that I suspect I might need WinDbg to find.

Comment: does the light toggle or not?

Comment: yes. the caps lock toggles.   the mouse also moves, so the NT kernel is alive, but all user mode processes are hung. task manager will not open, ctrl-alt-del has no effect.  It has happened 10 times, on 3 different Windows 10 kernel versions (fall creators update and insider preview builds)

Comment: open cmd.exe as admin run **wpr.exe -start CPU && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\hang.etl** and minimize the cmd. after you get recovered from the hang, go back to CMD and press a key to stop logging. now zip the ETL + PDB folder and share the zip

Comment: Ok this is nuts. After running less than 5 minutes, the wpr.exe -stop fails with:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wpr.exe -stop C:\hang.etl
        There is not enough space on the disk.
        Profile Id: RunningProfile
        Error code: 0x80070070
        There is not enough space on the disk.

I have over 100 gigs of free space. Is it really gonna write a file over 100 gigs?

Comment: 100GB is way too large. change C:\ to D:\ or any other drive with a lot of space.